# launch Qt Creator without Ubuntu SDK add-ons

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator

I want to launch Qt Creator without the additional Ubuntu SDK features.  Sometimes I need them and sometimes I don't.

Is this possible without uninstalling the SDK?  If it is not how can you also uninstall the SDK?

Running 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable plugins at start of qtcreator.

```
qtcreator -noload <plugin>
```

Where `<plugin>` is the name of the ubuntu sdk plugin in your system.

Comment: what is the name of the plugin?

Comment: You can search for the name in `Help > About plugins`.